# Unable to use ConfigurableWroManagerFactory in wro4j-maven-plugin (NPE)

Tags: java, maven, wro4j

I'm getting an NPE when using the `ConfigurableWroManagerFactory` wroManagerFactory and can't seem to trace down the cause. It seems that `Context.get().getFilterConfig();` returns null..

Stacktrace (this is the root cause of a `WroRuntimeException`)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory.updatePropertiesWithConfiguration(ConfigurableWroManagerFactory.java:202)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory.access$000(ConfigurableWroManagerFactory.java:45)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory$1.newProperties(ConfigurableWroManagerFactory.java:86)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.support.AbstractConfigurableStrategySupport.getProperties(AbstractConfigurableStrategySupport.java:136)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.support.AbstractConfigurableStrategySupport.getConfiguredValue(AbstractConfigurableStrategySupport.java:52)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.support.AbstractConfigurableMultipleStrategy.getConfiguredStrategies(AbstractConfigurableMultipleStrategy.java:52)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.locator.factory.ConfigurableLocatorFactory.newLocatorFactory(ConfigurableLocatorFactory.java:69)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.locator.factory.ConfigurableLocatorFactory.<init>(ConfigurableLocatorFactory.java:38)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory$1.<init>(ConfigurableWroManagerFactory.java:82)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory.newUriLocatorFactory(ConfigurableWroManagerFactory.java:82)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.BaseWroManagerFactory$1.initialize(BaseWroManagerFactory.java:96)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.BaseWroManagerFactory$1.initialize(BaseWroManagerFactory.java:73)
    at ro.isdc.wro.util.LazyInitializer.get(LazyInitializer.java:32)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.BaseWroManagerFactory.create(BaseWroManagerFactory.java:156)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.BaseWroManagerFactory.create(BaseWroManagerFactory.java:51)
    at ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.AbstractWro4jMojo.getWroManager(AbstractWro4jMojo.java:452)
    ... 26 more
```

`wro4j.version` is 1.7.0

Plugin entry in my `pom.xml`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jsDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/static/js</jsDestinationFolder>
                <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/static/css</cssDestinationFolder>
                <ignoreMissingResources>false</ignoreMissingResources>
                <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and my `wro.properties`

```
#If true, it is DEVELOPMENT mode, by default this value is true
debug=true
# Default is true
gzipEnabled=true

# MBean name to be used if JMX is enabled
#mbeanName=wro
#jmxEnabled=true

# Default is 0
cacheUpdatePeriod=0
# Default is 0
modelUpdatePeriod=0
# Default is false.
disableCache=false
# Default is UTF-8
encoding=UTF-8

managerFactoryClassName=ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory
preProcessors=jsLint,lessCssImport,cssUrlRewriting,cssImport,semicolonAppender
postProcessors=googleClosureSimple,less4j

resourceWatcherUpdatePeriod=5
```

Comment: Could you try with version 1.7.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the build-time solution (maven plugin), you should use

```
ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory
```

Notice that this class is in a different package the the one used by you.
Also, try upgrading to version 1.7.1.

Comment: Thanks. Changing to use the `...maven.plugin.manager.` package did the trick~

Comment: How much of the `wro.properties` configuration is shared with the maven plugin? For example, do I need to specify `<ignoreMissingResources>` in the pom plugin if it already exists in `wro.properties`?

Comment: The one from the pom plugin configuration takes precedence to the one from wro.properties. I know this is confusing and probably this is something can be improved in the future.

Comment: Update: even more, the property from wro.properties is always overriden by the one from plugin configuration in pom.xml.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Just to confirm -- does it fall back on the `wro.properties` option if it doesn't exist in the `pom.xml` plugin configuration?

Comment: When this property doesn't exist in pom.xml, it is defaulted to true. In the end, it doesn't matter what you put in wro.properties, since the default value will override it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38186/discussion-between-alex-objelean-and-jlb)